# Reading Google Spreadsheet (Java): IndexOutOfBounds exception when row's last cell(s) empty

Tags: java, google-sheets

My method returns a range from a google spreadsheet, and cycles through its rows, and then each cell in a row. When the final cell/ cells of a given row in the spreadsheet range are empty, the method fails with an IndexOutOfBoundsException (Index 36 out of bounds for length 36). I think this is telling me that the length of a row returned is only the length up to the final non-blank cell.

It is necessary in my application that blank cells at the end of rows can be handled; I need each row to be considered its full length with my variable currentCellValue being assigned an empty string for a blank cell. Can someone help please?

My method:

```
        List<List<Object>> tableContents = SheetsQuickstart.getValues("FC_Input!A2:AN900");

        int[] columnNumbers = ColumnOps.fillColumnNumbersArray();
        
        //Cycle through rows
        for (List row : tableContents) {
            String currentCellValue = "";
            int currentColumnNumber = -1;
            
            //Cycle through cells
            for (int column : columnNumbers) {
                currentColumnNumber++;
                currentCellValue = row.get(currentColumnNumber).toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think adding a null check before toString should solve this issue. That might be the reason for NPE

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow you - do you mean enclosing the toString line with `if (row.get(currentColumnNumber) != null) {` ? If so that didn't work

Comment: What happens if the last two cells are empty?

Comment: If the last 2 cells of any row are empty, the method fails with IndexOutOfBoundsException (Index 38 out of bounds for length 38). If last 3 are empty, it's 'index 37', etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do, on the documentation is stated that if the last empty rows are empty the method omits them.

You can find it on the [Read a single range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range) documentation:

> The following spreadsheets.values.get request reads the values stored in the range Sheet1!A1:D5 and returns them in the response. **Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted**.